# Parsing in JavaScript for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that extracts all short url with the form e.g. `ini/ini#8012` from any page using a regex.

```
var regex = /[\w]+.[\w]+#(?:\d*\.)?\d+/g;
```

What I want to do is to make that short url into a clickable link in my popup window, and parse it into my web app, so clicking any short url in the list would take you to a web app. The web app url is like this

```
http://192.101.21.1889:8000/links/?user_repo=ini%2Fini&artID=8012&tc=4&tm=years&rows=5&submit=
```

The `user_repo`, and `ID` characters are from the extracted short url. First of all, is this possible? And if it is can anyone point me in the right direction as to what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Content Scripts and inject JavaScript, then perform whatever you want to do.

Readings:

- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)